# Changing the role of Corresponding author in a Journal for APC charges

Tags: publications

I wrote a research paper while i was doing my Postdoc at a university. Later I submitted one of research paper after the completion of my Postdoc. I submitted my paper to IEEE Access which charges APC (Article processing charges). My university (where I completed my Postdoc) facilitates with the payment of APC however the corresponding author needs to be from that university at the time of acceptance. Previously I (first author)did all the communication with the journal and I  mentioned myself as a corresponding author, but now I want to change the corresponding author to the second author of the paper so that we are facilitated in the payment of fees. Is it possible and does it sound rude to ask professor for funding after the completion of the Postdoc.

Comment: This is confusing. Which university is which? You say "My university..." Is that your current university or a former one?

Comment: Sorry, the formal one